# I got an invisible hat in notification bar

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

"Universe Brain" is almost invisible in notification bar:

[image: almost invi]

A darker shade of yellow, or maybe a border/shadow can help in this case.

Comment: applies to "Cosmic Brain" as well.